# Burndown/burnup widget not showing data (Stacked Bar) for current iteration in Azure DevOps Dashboards

Tags: azure-devops, widget, scrum

I’m a project admin for a few Scrum projects in our Azure DevOps collection. I’ve noticed when using either the Burndown or Burnup Widget in the dashboard, it won’t show bar data for the current sprint (iteration) you’re on. It’ll show stacked bars for all other previous iterations but not the current iteration in works. Once the current iteration is finished and moves on to the next iteration, it will then display the bar data for the iteration that just finished.

My question is, is this normal operation where either Burndown/Burnup won’t show bar data until the current iteration ends? If it is, is there a way to show bar data for current iteration? I’m on Azure DevOps Server 2020

Thank you
[My pov of my Burnup widget with no bar data on the current iteration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpoLs.png)

I messed with the widget configuration settings to no avail. I also skimmed through the Microsoft documentation about these widgets, but they didn't have information about my question. This is happening through all my projects. I'm expecting the Burndown/burnup widget to show bar as the rest of the previous sprints.